# How to fix 'Error in sdata[[paste0("Y", usc(resp))]] : subscript out of bounds' in R, using brms package

Tags: r, stan

I'm trying to set up priors for my MLM using brms. I have ran my model with the priors I had set with no error messages and now would like to check them using pp_check. I get an the 'Error in sdata[[paste0("Y", usc(resp))]] : subscript out of bounds' error and couldn't find any tips as to why this is happening. Thanks!

Edit: I have checked the structure of my fit and only the init variables are 0, which I think should be the case since I set the initialisation parameter to 0? Otherwise there is nothing problematic as I can see.

I couldn't try anything since googling led to nothing.

```
library(brms)
df <- data.frame( subjno = as.factor(c('sub-01', 'sub-01','sub-01','sub-01','sub02','sub02','sub02','sub02')),
              L1 = c(0.898922096, -0.673393065, -2.240150247,-0.932520537, -0.472701111, -0.188825324,0.808675919, 0.293666248), 
              L2 = c(0.64888, 2.0891, -0.655322708, 0.007098555, -0.648887797, -0.249716343, -0.698128026,0.119511014), 
              W1 = c(0.5,0.5,-0.5,-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5,-0.5), W2 = c(0.5,-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5,0.5,-0.5,-0.5),
              t = as.factor(c(12,23,34,45,12,23,34,45)))

ff_s = brmsformula(cbind(L1,L2) ~ W1 * W2 * t +  
                     (W1*W2* t|p|subjno)) 

get_prior(formula = ff_s, family = gaussian(),
      data = df)

pp_s <- c(set_prior('normal(0,1)', class = "b"),  
    set_prior("normal(0,10)", class = "sd", resp = 'L1'), 
    set_prior("normal(0,10)", class = "sd", resp = 'L2'), 
    set_prior("normal(0,5)", class = "sigma",resp = 'L1'), 
    set_prior("normal(0,5)", class = "sigma",resp = 'L2'),
    set_prior("normal(0,10)", class = "Intercept", resp = 'L1'),
    set_prior("normal(0,10)", class = "Intercept", resp = 'L2'),
    set_prior("lkj(3)", class = "cor"))

fit_s <- brm(formula = ff_s, 
          data = df, family = gaussian(),
          prior = pp_s,
          chains = 6, cores = 3,
          iter = 2e3, warmup = 1e3,
          init = 0,
          sample_prior = "only")

pp_check(fit_s)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your code does not work for us, because we have no access to your data in `MR_brms`. There are two things to try. First, try to explore your `brm` run result with `str(fit_rt)`, which prints a structure of an object. What slots are there in the results? Which are empty and should not be? Does it help in getting to a result? If not, try to amend your question so that you provide a minimal, verifiable, complete example that replicates the problem (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi, thank you! Just did that and will update. I ran the str() function but I'm not sure if anything problematic is left empty, I have no experience in reading this out. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I was calling the function pp_check without specifying the level I am interested in, problem solved!